# How to fetch API data as this. props?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to fetch data from API in react component as

`{this.props.buyer && this.props.buyer[0].phone_number[0].number}` - it's throwing error

> Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

`{this.props.buyer && this.props.buyer[0].name}` - it's working fine

This is the API data

```html
Orders: {
buyer:
},
}
[
 {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Qi Xiang",
 "type": "Consignee",
 "address": {
 "id": 2,
 "type": "shipping",
 "street": "China China",
 "city": "Beijing",
 "postal_code": "34343",
 "province": "23232",
 "country": "CN"
 },
 "email": null,
 "phone_number": {
 "number": "323232",
 "type": "Phone"
 },
 "id_image_url": "/api/files/24e49645-df42-4984-a
 }
]
},
}
```

Comment: because phonenumber is not array. try:  this.props.buyer[0].phone_number.number

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Just a silly mistake.

Comment: your API data as shown here doesn't make sense (check the brackets and commas, they are all over the place), can you try to copy&paste the real data? but yeah, looks like phone_number is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `phonenumber` is not array. You must use this:

```
this.props.buyer[0].phone_number.number
```